# push data of an API to local data.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, object

Hello Everyone Help me with the issue which I am facing i have a file called data.js it contains some obj locally and I made a request to an API and got some obj back I want to save that obj in my data.js file

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

wanted to add the data in the data.js file

Comment: There's a lot of reasons why this sounds like a bad idea. What's the end goal here? Maybe someone can suggest a better approach than storing API calls to a `.js` file.

Comment: I think you should really consider database for this stuff. Saving data to file is not a good idea.
But if for some reason you must, consider JSON instead.